How to work with multiple models loaded into one scene using ThatOpen libraries?
ThatOpen libraries and Three.js support loading multiple models into one scene and displaying the models. However, I have not found a way to display the entity properties of each model, floor plans and the entity tree of the merged models.
It appears that only the first loaded model is processed.
Can you please advise on how to work with multiple models loaded into one scene?
I am using FragmentIfcLoader.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
